# Environmental effects of global volcano eruption

Tags: science-based, planets, apocalypse, near-future, earth

Imagine that one day [all Earth volcanoes](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/185162/36) has erupted [in the same moment](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/185164/36). What impact would such event has on nature and environment?

How would running lava, ash and gases blowing from volcanoes impact:

- air and atmosphere (Sun visibility, breathable air),
- rivers, lakes, seas and oceans,
- mountains, caves, stone formations etc. (if any),
- animals.

Since in this vision [entire human population is gone](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/185162/36), I assume that the same happens to all ground species. But what about birds and ocean life?

Comment: It depends on what you mean by *"all"* the volcanoes, and also on for how long they erupt. The first element is crucial; for example, is [Yellowstone a volcano](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yellowstone_Caldera) or isn't it? The second element is also important; it's one thing for "all" the volcanos to erupt for a few hours and quite another for them to erupt for a few hundred thousand years.

Comment: I think that answers to your questions are already addressed in my linked questions. I.e. [all as in each and everyone](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/185162/36) and also some other "holes" eruptions if all volcanoes that are there on Earth are not enough. And (in the same question) -- erupting as long as it is possible or as long as it is needed to [cover entire planet surface](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/185162/36).

Comment: [We closed one like this](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/78941/40609). This is way, way, way, way, way too broad. Way too broad! All animals? You want to know how this would affect mice and chickadees? geology? All surface water? All climate and atmosphere?  An entire lifetime of serious study in geoscience and volcanography might (maybe!) answer this question with an entire series of books. This violates the [help] tremendously and is basically writing your story for you.

Comment: @JBH I see your point. Seems that my research prior asking too good. Sorry. From your perspective and example given, I have nothing else to add except for agreeing that my question is also too broad.

Comment: Permian-Triassic extinction event: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permian%E2%80%93Triassic_extinction_event  You don't need all volcanos, and don't need them all at the same time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Ice age

Ignore the lava, ignore the gases, they don't really do that much in the scheme of things. The only thing that we need to focus on is the dust and ash cloud in the atmosphere.

[Paektu Eruption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/946_eruption_of_Paektu_Mountain#Climate_effects) 
caused anomalous weather (ice, frost, cold harsh weather, or unexpected snow) across China and Japan for the following 3 years.

[Pinatubo Eruption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1991_eruption_of_Mount_Pinatubo#Global_environmental_effects) dropped the amount of sunlight reaching the earth surface by 10%, lowing the global temperature by about 0.4 degrees C. It hung around for 3 years, and may of helped caused [the storm of the century](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1993_Storm_of_the_Century)

Blow any single large volcano, we will get a [Volcanic Winter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volcanic_winter).

Blow them all at once - we're going to freeze.

Comment: Your name is fitting